# Camel Proxy and Replacing Exchange body

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I have created a proxy for service.

There is a processor in between proxy (request is of type `TypeA`) and real service (request is of type `TypeB`).

The Exchange body which comes into the `process(Exchange exchange)` method is of `TypeA`.

I am able to access the data using following line of code

```
TypeA typeA = exchange.getIn().getBody(TypeA.class);
```

Now, I wanted to change this information to `TypeB`.

I am adding the body using following line.

```
exchange.getIn().setBody(typeA);
```

I got the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch`

Now, I wanted to call the real service using the `Exchange` which come out of the `Processor`.

I tried and got in Processor the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.cxf.databinding.AbstractWrapperHelper.createWrapperObject(AbstractWrapperHelpe
```

The real web service is not getting invoked.

How to fix this.

I am using POJO mode in proxy.

Comment: you need to provide more details before anyone can help you. There is not much details, and unclear what the problem is etc. eg spend more time to write down better questions so people better can help you.

Comment: Please check the modified code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works without any problems:

```
private static class ResetBodyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from("direct:start")
            .process(new Processor() {
               @Override
               public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                   final ClassA a = exchange.getIn().getBody(ClassA.class);
                   LOG.info("body = " + a);
                   exchange.getIn().setBody(new ClassB());  // reset the body
               }
            })
            .log("body = ${body}");
    }
}

public class ClassA {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "I'm A";
    }
};

public class ClassB {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "I'm B";
    }
};
```

This prints:

```
[                          main] ResetBody                      INFO  body = I'm A
[                          main] route1                         INFO  body = I'm B
```

Comment: It was my mistake, As mentioned the argument type was not correct, I was passing the wrong argument to the real service. Cool example :)